# Cross Apply table to itself using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a subset of entries from a table where the previous entry is a certain number of days later (2 in this case):

```
select t.*, DATEDIFF(day,f.gamedate, t.gamedate) diff
from Games t
cross apply (select TOP 1 t2.GameDate from Games t2 
where (t2.TeamID = T.TeamID) and t2.GameDate + 2 =  t.GameDate 
order by t2.GameDate Desc) f
```

How would I achieve the same thing using LINQ?

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to match the description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, there's an added constraint based on the TeamID. IE "find all games where the playing team (based on teamID) previously played 2 days ago". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would cache the last played date for each team, then go through all games and select the games that satisfy your definition of "played 2 days ago" (could mean played at least 2 days ago, precisely 2 days ago, at least 2 but no more than 3 days ago, etc...)

```
var lastPlayedQuery = (from game in Game
                      group game by game.TeamID into g
                      let lastPlayedDate = g.Select(x => x.GameDate).Max()
                      select new { TeamID = game.TeamID, LastPlayedDate = lastPlayedDate }).ToDictionary(x => x.TeamID, x => x.LastPlayedDate);

var gamesTwoDaysLater = from game in Games
                        let lastPlayedDate = lastPlayedQuery[game.TeamID]
                        let elapsedDays = (game.GameDate - lastPlayedDate).TotalDays
                        where elapsedDays >= 2.00 && elapsedDays < 3.00
                        select game;
```

---

Edit: Find all pairs of games seperated by two days

```
var teamGameLookup = Games.ToLookup(x => x.TeamID);

var twoDayApartGames = from game in Games
                       join secondGame in teamGameLookup[game.TeamID]
                       on game.GameDate.Date equals secondGame.GameDate.Date.AddDays(2)
                       select new { Game = game, GameTwoDaysEarlier = secondGame };
```

---

Edit: Find all pairs of games separated by between X to Y days

```
 var teamGameLookup = Games.ToLookup(x => x.TeamID);

    var seperatedGames = from game in Games
                         join otherGame in teamGameLookup[game.GameID]
                         on DatesWithinRange(game.GameDate,otherGame.GameDate,2,25) equals true
                         let daysApart = (game.GameDate - otherGame.GameDate).TotalDays
                         select new { Game = game, OtherGame = otherGame, DaysApart = daysApart};

    private bool DatesWithinRange(DateTime firstDate, DateTime secondDate, float lower, float higher)
    {
         float elapsedDays = (secondDate - firstDate).TotalDays;
         return elapsedDays >= lower && elapsedDays <= higher;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I keep misstating the problem. I think the above returns games where the team played literally 2 days ago. What I'm after is games where the team played 2 days previosly...

Comment: @qi1 So you want to find all pairs of games that were played 2 days apart regardless of the current date?

Comment: Great, nice and simple. Thank you for the answer and the patience. Any way of doing similar where there's a date range, eg 2 - 25 days?

Comment: @qi1 yup it's possible, but the join syntax is slightly unnatural